# how to put hashtable session value into a list< model> and display in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have Session values in the form of hashtable and i have to display this data using model binding,So that i have to convert it into a list of that modal and display into view
What i have tried is:

```
 public ActionResult cart()
        {
            Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Session["cart"];
            List<cart> cart=new List<cart>();         
            cart = (List<cart>)(Hashtable)Session["cart"]; 
             return View("cart",cart);
         }
```

**Here ht contains the session value**

> Defenition

```
     if (Session["cart"] != null)
                {

                    Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Session["cart"];

                    var mydata = new List<cart>
                    {
                        new cart { mid= mid, mprize = mrate },
                    };

                    //Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

                        ht.Add(mid,mydata);

                    Session["Cart"] = ht;
}
```

and **how to access this hashtable values for displaying in my context**?

Comment: The `Hastable` cannot be implicitly converted to a `List`, you need to code the conversion.

Comment: @Rakesh i looked for that.But i didnt get solution to convert it

Comment: The code depends on your `HashTable`, show us its definition.

Comment: @Rakesh i updated my code ,please have a look,I dont know its right

Comment: Looking at your code, you are adding `mydata` to the `Hashtable` multiple times - `for (var i = 0; i < mydata.Count; i++){ht.Add(mid,mydata);}`

Comment: @Rakesh to be frank am a newbie in this,Can u suggest me the solution

Comment: I do not know your business case, but if you have added the data properly to your `Hastable`, you can access the items using the `Values` property of the `Hastable`. You can then convert that to the appropriate `List`

Answer (score 1):

You can get data in Views directly via this way

```
@foreach (var e in (Hashtable)HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"])
{
    // display item here. 
}
```